# Copy few rows between databases via dblink in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I would like to copy few rows between my PostgreSQL two databases (A and B) which are in one local server.

I know it is probably possible via dblink extension, but I haven’t found the answer how to create query `SELECT from Database A and INSERT via dblink into Database B` ?

Answer (score 0):

A simple google search would have sufficed.

[PostgreSQL documentation on dblinks](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/contrib-dblink-function.html)

[Stackoverflow answer to exactly your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6083132/postgresql-insert-into-select)

**EDIT:** To insert rows / data from local database A into remote database B, you'll need [Postgres-FDW](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/postgres-fdw.html), because a simple `INSERT INTO remotetable SELECT * FROM localtable` won't work with PostgreSQL.

Comment: Nope that not helps me, I DON'T want to run query from database B and query to A, vice versa `SELECT FROM A` and `INSERT INTO B` via dblink..

Comment: So I reckon database B is _not_ under your direct control? Because then you could of course run the query on B. You can achieve what you want via [postgres foreign data wrapper, or postgres-fdw](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/postgres-fdw.html), but it's a bit more...complicated.

Comment: I want to run query `SELECT few rows` into database A side, and these rows via dblink insert into database B.

Comment: @Uzumymw erm, yeah, that's what my second link is for. I'll update the answer itself.